# Unable to retrieve data and display in listview

Tags: android, listview, parsing, fetch

Here is my code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listview;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> mylist;
String name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mylist = new ArrayList<>();

    parseDataFetch();


}

public void parseDataFetch()
{
    if (FragmentA.item == "first") {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("menu");
        query.whereEqualTo("type", "testRow");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> nameList, ParseException e)
            {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject object : nameList) {
                         name = object.getString("itemName");
                        mylist.add(name);
                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MenuActivity.this, R.layout.activity_menu, mylist);
                    }
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Only text is displayed but no images are being displayed, and its not working..

Please help, what is the problem with it as there are no errors generated.

Comment: try checking your response  is coming or not, May be your response is null

Comment: Where you setting up the image from response ? I can only see item name

Comment: Please set the adapter initialization outside the loop.............                   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MenuActivity.this, R.layout.activity_menu, mylist);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact you are using `==` to compare strings...

Move this to onCreate

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MenuActivity.this, R.layout.activity_menu, mylist);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Inside the loop, simply do

```
adapter.add(name);
```

Comment: i did that..its still not fetching data.. showing invalid session token exception.. i dropped the class and recreated it the problem still persists..i removed the string comparison line too by the way it didn't help..

Comment: That's a Parse Server error. I suggest you check your API key and Application ID values